# find angle x in isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

Considering the attached image, is that possible to compute for $\angle x$ in the isosceles triangle below, with no further known values?

$\\$I have found $\angle B$ and $\angle C$ are $50^o$. So $\angle B$ is divided by $\overline{BP}$ to $10^o$ and $40^o$. But I can't find how the $\angle C$ is divided by $\overline{CP}$. Also its clear that $\overline{BP}$ is perpendicular to leg $\overline{AC}$.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Please edit your question to add your thoughts on this problem—what have you tried?

Comment: You might try the [trigonometric form of Ceva's theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/TrigCeva.shtml)

Comment: If you know that $BP$ is perpendicular to $AC$, you might try extending $BP$ to cross through $AC$ at a point $D$. Then $\triangle ADP$, $\triangle PDC$, and $\triangle BPC$ are all right triangles. That may make it easier to draw conclusions.

Comment: @Semiclassical $\triangle BPC$ isn't a right triangle, it has angles 40°, 110°, 30°. Perhaps that's a typo, and you meant to write $\triangle BDC$.

Comment: @PM2Ring woops, you're right

Comment: Hi @Semiclassical. I used Ceva's theorem to solve the problem. If you want, it will be appreciated if you add another way to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Construct equilateral triangle $ABX$ as in the picture.

Note that the concave angle $BXA$ equals $300^\circ = 2\cdot 150^\circ = 2\angle BPA$, hence $P$ lies on the circle with center $X$ and radius $XA=XB$. It follows that $\angle PXB = 2\angle PAB = 40^\circ$.

On the other hand, $AB=AX=AC$, so $A$ is the circumcenter of triangle $BXC$, hence $\angle CXB = \frac 12 \cdot \angle CAB = \frac 12 \cdot 80^\circ = 40^\circ$.

Since $\angle PXB = 40^\circ = \angle CXB$, points $X, P, C$ are collinear.

Since $AC=AX$, we have $\angle PCA = \angle AXP = 2\cdot \angle ABP = 20^\circ$, hence $$\angle APC = 180^\circ - \angle CAP - \angle PCA = 180^\circ - 60^\circ - 20^\circ = 100^\circ.$$

[image]

Comment: Beautifully done - I feel like that $150^\circ$ angle will always suggest adding an equilateral tringle to me now...

Comment: @Joffan Thanks for attaching a nice picture!

Comment: @timon92 beatiful answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the figure below.
[image]
$\\$Thanks to **@saulspatz** answer, and based on [Trigonometric Form of Ceva's Theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/TrigCeva.shtml) we may write the following:
$$Sin(\angle B1).Sin(\angle C1).Sin(\angle A1) = Sin(\angle B2).Sin(\angle C2).Sin(\angle A2)$$
$$\\$$so we have:
$$\frac{Sin(\angle C1)}{Sin(\angle C2)} = \frac{Sin(40^o)*Sin(20^o)}{Sin(10^o)*Sin(60^o)}$$
$\\$Also we have $\angle C1 + \angle C2 = 50^o$, and by solving for $\angle C2$:

$$\angle C2 = 20^o$$

$\\$Hence:
$$\angle x = 100^o$$